# How to enable JavaScript Policy in keycloak 18.0.2

Tags: keycloak, fiware

I'm using the quay.io/keycloak instance (18.0.2-legacy) via docker-compose yaml file and the JavaScript Policy is disabled (as default).
I'm trying to set the JAVA_OPTS_APPEND in the environment without success:

```
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2-legacy
    container_name: keycloak
    ...
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      ...
      JAVA_OPTS_APPEND: -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled  
      ...
```

Could you suggest me how to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

Keycloak does not natively support declarative configuration of realms, clients, users and therefore also there policies. Thus, you cannot directly configure it in the compose of your keycloak.
However, there is a tool called https://github.com/adorsys/keycloak-config-cli that I use in all my deployments to just get that functionality. You would have to create a json-definition of the objects you want to create(see the examples for some options, not sure if one for javascript is available: https://github.com/adorsys/keycloak-config-cli/blob/main/contrib/example-config/moped.json) and add the cli-container to your compose. I do use it via kubernetes, thus I dont have a docker-compose example myself, but there is one included in the tools github: https://github.com/adorsys/keycloak-config-cli/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L50

If you are unsure on how to create the json, a good starting point it to just configure through the UI and then use the "export-realm" functionality(include clients and roles). It will generate a json-representation of your realm, with the javascript config included.
Another example(with javascript, but a slightly outdate keycloak) can be found here:
https://github.com/FIWARE-Ops/marinera/blob/main/applications/keycloak/chart/templates/realmConfigmap.yaml#L463
Best